# How do I get the pendant of power in A Link Between Worlds?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I can't seem to figure out how to get up to the dungeon in the mountain. Can somebody please tell me how?

Comment: It would be better if you added what exactly was blocking you. Edit your question and add more information, there's nothing to go on there.

Answer (score 2):

To get to the Tower of Hera on top of Death Mountain you need to head north west of the Castle towards the forest towards the cave at the west of the mountain, behind a stone that requires the Power Glove to remove, south of where the lumberjacks are located:

[image]

[Navigate the cave](http://www.thonky.com/zelda-link-to-the-past/up-the-mountain) and you'll come across an old man who will give you the Magic Mirror, lead him out of the cavern and head east towards his home, watch out for the rocks falling down the mountain that you need to avoid. Once the old man has given you the Magic Mirror head east up some steps towards another entrance in the mountain. Following this cavern will bring you out on top of the mountain.

Head east and enter the portal to the Dark World. You'll see two strangers, one kicking the other around, you can largely ignore them, near them you'll see the outline of Spectacle Rock in the light world on the ground

[image: spectacle rock in the dark world]

Stand in this space within the marked area and use the Magic Mirror and you will teleport back to the Light World on top of Spectacle Rock. Heading north from here will jump you off the top of Spectacle Rock, next to the Tower of Hera.